# Getting many rows through joined tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have the id of an album and I'd like to get all the tracks from an album with their artists. An **album has many tracks**. A **track has many producers** (artists).

**MySQL Structure**

[image: Database structure]

**Problem**

I don't know if I can do it in full mySQL or if I should add some PHP instead.

**EDIT :** My question wasn't clear enough. The problem wasn't the fact of doing a query with joined table but to get the tracks with a list of the artists. You can handle that with group_concat.

**Tutorial :** http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/04/group_concat-useful-group-by-extension/

Comment: Do it with pure mySQL

Comment: Do whatever's easiest for you first, then the other solution may become more apparent.

Comment: do u know the id of the ablum whose track u want to fetch ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how you need the data. If you're more interested in the artists then you can join tracks on albums and then artists onto tracks. This will give you a record for each artist.

```
SELECT
    ar.*
FROM albums AS al
JOIN tracks AS t
    ON t.album_id = al.album_id
JOIN produced AS p
    ON p.produced_track = t.track_id
JOIN artists AS ar
    ON ar.artist_id = p.produced_artist
```

If you're more interested in the tracks and just need to list the artists then do the same join but use group_concat on the artist name and group by the track id

```
SELECT
    t.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ar.name ORDER BY ar.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS artists
FROM albums AS al
JOIN tracks AS t
    ON t.album_id = al.album_id
JOIN produced AS p
    ON p.produced_track = t.track_id
JOIN artists AS ar
    ON ar.artist_id = p.produced_artist
GROUP BY t.track_id
```

Comment: Group concat was the solution! Thanks a lot, my question wasn't enough clear!

Answer (score 0):

Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   Tracks
  JOIN Produced ON Produced.produced_track = Tracks.track_id
  JOIN Artists  ON Artists.artist_id = Produced.produced_artists
WHERE  Tracks.track_album = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best just to do this in pure SQL like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM albums al
LEFT JOIN tracks tr ON (tr.ttack_album = al.album_id)
LEFT JOIN produced pr ON (pr.produced_track = tr.track_id)
LEFT JOIN artists ar ON (ar.artist_id = pr.produced_artist)
WHERE al.album_id = thealbumid;
```

However there's nothing preventing you from doing separate queries depending on how you need to use the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can, and you should, do that with pure MySQL, have three tables, link them with foreign keys, and query using JOINs.

You don't need PHP to overload the work, MySQL can handle it just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`LEFT JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html) to achieve this with mysql only:

```
SELECT * FROM Albums a
LEFT JOIN Tracks b
ON a.album_id = b.track_album
LEFT JOIN Produced c
on b.track_id = c.produced_track
LEFT JOIN Artist d
on c.produced_artist = d.artist_id
WHERE a.album_id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in SQL using aggregate functions and group by clause.

It should look like:
    select t.*,
           some_aggregate_function(a.whatever)
    from      Tracks t
    left join Produced p on (t.trac_id = p.produced_id)
    left join Artist a on (p.produced_artist = a.artist_id)
    group by t.*